# Kotlin - Multi Thread with Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, android-livedata, observer-pattern

i have more than 5 api calls in one fragment. Doing this, the app get slower in performance loading.

So i planned to make it run parallel with kotlin. How to use executors, threads in my code.

I implemented api in below format.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    viewModel.callApiOne()
    viewModel.callApiTwo()
    viewModel.callApiThree()

    viewModel.getResponseInViewModel().observe(this.viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        if (it.errorResponse?.code() == 200) {
            
        }
    })
}
```

`ViewModel.kt`

```
fun callApiOne() {
    repository.callApiOne()
}
fun getResponseInViewModel(): MutableLiveData<Resource<Model>> {
    respp = repository.getResponse()
    return respp
}
```

`Repository.kt`

```
private val resp by lazy { MutableLiveData<Resource<Model>>() }
  
   fun callApiOne() {
        val api = AppMain.restClient?.services?.callApiOne()
        api?.enqueue(object : Callback<Model> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Model>, t: Throwable) {
                resp.postValue(Resource.failure(t.message!!, null))
            }

            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<Model>,
                response: Response<Model>
            ) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    resp.postValue(Resource.successResp(response))
                } else {
                    resp.postValue(Resource.errorresponse(response))
                }
            }

        })

    }
    
    fun getResponse(): MutableLiveData<Resource<Model>> = resp
```

Comment: You can use `async` with calling 5 api at a time. More information: https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-adv?authuser=3#start

Comment: Aren't these already running in parallel? You `enqueue` them so Retrofit is handling the asynchronous work on its own in parallel. You're getting your results in LiveData, so it's not blocking the main thread. But you only showed one LiveData even though there are three different requests, so maybe you've omitted too much code for us to be able to tell what you're trying to do.

Comment: But still it is slow in performance. And yes i have omitted too much code

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to use coroutines in this case.

Example:

```
MyFragment : Fragment(), CoroutineScope by MainScope() {
...

    private fun init() {
       launch { // starts a coroutine on main thread
          viewModel.fooSuspend()
       }
    }
}


MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
...

    suspend fun fooSuspend() {
       withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { //do on IO Thread
          doIOHaveOperation()
       }
    }
}
```